# Summing Array Elements from Specific Index Range

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have tried to look at many things for this but I simply cannot figure out how to make it work. I am very new to coding in general, so it may be a lack of understanding! Simply put, I have a an array with a set amount of elements, and I want to be able to sum up consecutive elements, starting from a specific index and ending at specific index.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to be able to sum index 1 and 3, which in this case would be 2+4 =6.

Is there a way to use `array.filter()` or just use a function where I sum based on the `array.indexof()`?

Comment: Are you trying to sum all elements in a range or just two specific elements?

Comment: The sum of all elements from index 1 to 3 is not 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to sum all the elements between two indexes, you can use a simple index based for loop.

```
let start = 1, end = 3, sum = 0;
for(let i = start; i <= end; i++)
     sum += array[i];
```

`slice` and `reduce` can also be used:

```
let sum = array.slice(start, end+1).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0);
```

If you just want the sum of the elements at two specific indexes, you can access the elements using bracket notation.

```
let sum = array[1]+array[3];
```

If you have an array of indexes to sum, you can loop over each index like so:

```
let indexes = [1, 3], sum = 0;
for(let index of indexes){
    sum += array[index];
}
```

`reduce` can be used as well.

```
let indexes = [1, 3];
let sum = indexes.reduce((acc, cur)=>acc+array[cur],0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var startInd=1;
var endInd=3;
console.log(array[startInd]+array[endInd]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `slice` to take a chunk of the array and then use `reduce`

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
subar = array.slice(1,4)
res = subar.reduce((acc , curr, i) => acc = acc + curr ,0)
console.log(res)
```